# How to assess the assumption of conditional independence in latent class analysis (poLCA)?

Tags: latent-variable

I'm performing latent class modelling using [poLCA](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/poLCA) package in R. Below is an example from the documentation.

How to interpret `G^2`?

And how to assess whether the assumption of conditional independence holds between each two of the manifest variables `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`?

```
> library(poLCA)
> data(values)
> f <- cbind(A,B,C,D)~1

poLCA(f,values,nclass=3,maxiter=8000)

Conditional item response (column) probabilities,
by outcome variable, for each class (row) 

$A
Pr(1)  Pr(2)
class 1:  0.5188 0.4812
class 2:  0.0022 0.9978
class 3:  0.1557 0.8443

$B
Pr(1)  Pr(2)
class 1:  0.9053 0.0947
class 2:  0.0204 0.9796
class 3:  0.5013 0.4987

$C
Pr(1)  Pr(2)
class 1:  0.7310 0.2690
class 2:  0.0000 1.0000
class 3:  0.5522 0.4478

$D
Pr(1)  Pr(2)
class 1:  0.9251 0.0749
class 2:  0.0874 0.9126
class 3:  0.7983 0.2017

Estimated class population shares 
0.2266 0.193 0.5804 

Predicted class memberships (by modal posterior prob.) 
0.1435 0.1944 0.662 

========================================================= 
  Fit for 3 latent classes: 
  ========================================================= 
  number of observations: 216 
number of estimated parameters: 14 
residual degrees of freedom: 1 
maximum log-likelihood: -503.3011 

AIC(3): 1034.602
BIC(3): 1081.856
G^2(3): 0.3868563 (Likelihood ratio/deviance statistic) 
X^2(3): 0.4225484 (Chi-square goodness of fit)
```

Answer (score 1):

$G^2$ is the likelihood ratio. The package authors provide additional detail including its formula [here](http://www.sscnet.ucla.edu/polisci/faculty/lewis/pdf/poLCA-JSS-final.pdf). It is akin to $\chi^2$ (formula also provided in the same link) with large values indicating greater model-data misfit.

As for conditional independence, as the authors of the package point out:

> The latent class model seeks to stratify the cross-classification
>   table of observed (or, “manifest”) variables by an unobserved
>   (“latent”) unordered categorical variable that eliminates all
>   confounding between the manifest variables. Conditional upon values of
>   this latent variable, responses to all of the manifest variables are
>   assumed to be statistically independent; an assumption typically
>   referred to as “conditional” or “local” independence

If you would like to demonstrate conditional independence after you have settled on a latent class solution you can consider the [Cochran-Mantel-Haenszel](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat504/node/113) test.